# dcolumn and text in table header

Tags: tables, dcolumn

I am using the `dcolumn` package to align cell contents at the decimal seperator. Now in the table header I have a textual description of the column, for example like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|d{4.3}}
  field & \multicolumn{1}{c}{description} \\
  \hline
  a     &    0.55 \\
  b     & 1223.4
\end{tabular}
```

As you can see I had to wrap this text in `multicolumn` to make LaTeX happy which somehow is a hack. Is there a more elegant way? Especially for many columns this gets a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a hack, it is the correct approach. The `dcolumn` package works by inserting appropriate code before and after the cell contents to make the alignment work. Using `\multicolumn` skips insertion of the alignment code, which is exactly what you want.

You could use my `siunitx` package to do the alignment without using `\multicolumn`, but it might be overkill for this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format = 4.3]}
  \toprule
  field & {Description} \\
  \midrule
  a     &    0.55 \\
  b     & 1223.4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have indeed considered using `siunitx` instead which can do a lot of useful things, but as you say, it seemed to be overkill in this case.